# Grails domain validate keeps returning false positives for unit test

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

**What I want:** when I call validate (or save) on a parent domain during a unit test, it will check the constraints of all children domains AND their children AND their children etc.

**What is happening:** during a unit test for a service, validate keeps returning true despite constraints not being met for children domains. *Please help...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two change two things about my code:
1) I had to make sure all domains were mocked for the unit test.
2) I had to make sure each child domain's back reference to the parent was populated. obj.addToSomeProperty(property) automatically populated back references for one-to-many objects, but for one-to-one I had to set it manually.

Service Unit Test:

```
@TestFor(GardenerService)
@Mock([Orchard, Plot, Tree, Fruit])
class GardenerServiceSpec extends Specification {
    void "test save and fetch"() {
        setup:
        Fruit fruit = new Fruit(name:"Peach")
        Tree tree = new Tree(height:6)
        tree.addToFruits(fruit)
        Plot plot = new Plot(litersOfWaterAdded:10)

        plot.tree = tree  // Must be a better way... why didn't setTree(tree) 
        tree.plot = plot  //   set the back reference

        Orchard orchard = new Orchard(orchardName:"Eden")
        orchard.addToPlots(plot)

        when:
        orchard.save(flush: true)

        then:
        orchard.validate()
        Fruit.findByName("Peach").tree.plot.orchard.name == "Eden"
        Tree.findByHeight(6).plot.litersOfWaterAdded == 10
    }
}
```

Domains:

```
class Orchard {
    String orchardName
    static hasMany = [plots: Plot]
}

class Plot{
    static belongsTo = [orchard: Orchard]
    int litersOfWaterAdded
    static hasOne = [tree: Tree]
}

class Tree {
    static belongsTo = [plot: Plot]
    int height
    static hasMany = [fruits: Fruit]
}

class Fruit {
    static belongsTo = [tree: Tree]
    String name
    String description

    static constraints = { description nullable: true }
}
```